# Show that if $f$ is analytic and injective on the domain then it is a fractional transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z : |z+2|>1, |z-2|>1 \}$ and suppose that $f$ is analytic and injective with $f(D)=D$.  Show that $f$ is a linear fractional transformation.

My attempt:  If $f$ is not a polynomial then $f$ has an essential singularity at infinity and by Casorati-Weierstrass the set $A=f(\{|z|>10 \})$ is dense.  Since $f(\{ |z|<10 \})$ is open there is some element in $A$ that intersects it.  Since $f$ is 1-1, $f$ must be a polynomial.  Since every polynomial of degree $n$ is $n$ to $1$, $f$ must be a line.

The issue is that it seems I've proved something stronger.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the problem ask? Your statement  is supose $f$ analytic and injective, show that $f$ analytic and injective; note that since $D$ is not the full plane, there are lots of analytic functions on $D$ that do not have essential singularity  at infinity and are not polynomials; an inversion in one of the circle transforms $D$ into a region that is between two circles, one included in another but not necessarily  concentric; then there is a linear fractional  transformation that fixes the outer circle and sends the inner to a circle with same center as the outer

Comment: So the problem reduces to finding the conformal isomorphisms of an annulus and that is quite easy (hint rotations and inversions)

Comment: @Conrad could you say that either $f(\{ |z|<10 \})$ or $f(\{|z|>10 \})$ is unbounded and if the component $f(\{ |z|<10 \})$ is unbounded apply the argument to $f(1/(z-2))$?

Comment: No it doesn't  work that way - it is crucial  that the domain is the exterior of circles as otherwise statement is not true (eg replace circles with ellipses  that are not circular and the conformal isomorphisms become complicated)

Comment: This thread has a good answer walking through a similar problem https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1200439/444923

This one is good too https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3743443/444923